# Adding a cell value into multiple sheets with input box

Tags: vba, excel

My workbook contains multiple sheets, in each sheet row 8 contains column headers.  Each sheet has identical columns to the other sheets but the amount of columns will vary from job to job. I need to write a macro so that when a new column header is added to the end of one sheet, it adds it to all the other sheets (with a few exceptions which can be seen in my code).  The column name is controlled by an input box but as the number of columns can vary I can't fix the cell range when trying to use this value.

Here is the code I have at the moment.  I had no luck trying to add just the additional column name so I tried copying all the column names in row 8 but haven't been able to get it to work.  I'm quite new to VBA, any help would be appreciated!

```
Sub AddNewColumns()

Dim NewColumn As String
Dim rng As Range

NewColumn = InputBox("Please enter a name for the new column")

    Range("A8").Select
    ActiveCell.End(xlToRight).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select

    ActiveCell.Value = NewColumn

    Range("A8").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select

    Set rng = Selection

    Selection.Copy

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

    If ws.Name <> "SheetList" And ws.Name <> "Blank Sheet" And ws.Name <> "Dashboard" And ws.Name <> "Combined" And ws.Name <> "MasterCheck" Then

    ws.Range("A8").Value = rng.Value

    End If

    Next ws

End Sub
```

Thanks

Comment: You already have code that finds the last column, using End(xlToRight), use similar code in the other worksheets, or store the column index if the sheets are identical in layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a shot. Should be simple enough to understand on its own:

```
Option Explicit

Sub AddNewColumns()

    Dim newColumn As String
    newColumn = InputBox("Please enter a name for the new column")

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

        If ws.Name <> "SheetList" And ws.Name <> "Blank Sheet" And ws.Name <> "Dashboard" And ws.Name <> "Combined" And ws.Name <> "MasterCheck" Then

            ws.Range("A8").End(xlToRight).Offset(,1).Value = newColumn

        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you change the if statement to this, it will work:

```
If ws.Name <> "SheetList" And ws.Name <> "Blank Sheet" And ws.Name <> 
"Dashboard" And ws.Name <> "Combined" And ws.Name <> "MasterCheck" Then

        ws.Range(rng.Address).Value = rng.Value

    End If
```

and some slightly modified code for you to look at:

```
    Sub AddNewColumns()
    Dim strHeadingToInsert As String
    Dim wks As Worksheet

        strHeadingToInsert = InputBox("Please enter a name for the new column")


        For Each wks In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

            If wks.Name <> "SheetList" And wks.Name <> "Blank Sheet" And wks.Name <> "Dashboard" And wks.Name <> "Combined" And wks.Name <> "MasterCheck" Then

                wks.Range("A8").End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1) = strHeadingToInsert

            End If

        Next wks

    End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks so much!  Both work great and now I've got a few different solutions I can use again in the future :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all answers given, they all work great and there's a few options I can keep for future use :)

I went with the first option although all answers did the job

```
Option Explicit

Sub AddNewColumns()

Dim newColumn As String
newColumn = InputBox("Please enter a name for the new column")

Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

    If ws.Name <> "SheetList" And ws.Name <> "Blank Sheet" And ws.Name <> "Dashboard" And ws.Name <> "Combined" And ws.Name <> "MasterCheck" Then

        ws.Range("A8").End(xlToRight).Offset(,1).Value = newColumn

    End If

Next

End Sub
```